# TRUNCATE TABLE Hangs in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, truncate, mariadb

Iam trying to migrate from mysql to mariadb. This time I can face another issue with mariadb.

Sometimes the `TRUNCATE TABLE` query becomes hang. But in MySQL, this issue doesn't occured.

Can anyone help me in this regard??? Iam a newone in MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use :
TRUNCATE [TABLE] tbl_name
If this one is hang means some dependencies is exists on these table.
```

Comment: But the hang issue only seen in mariadb, why don't this seen in mysql?

Comment: If this one is hang means some dependencies is exists on these table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved in MariaDB 5.5.27.

Comment: Iam using the latest version 5.5.28

Comment: Issue now present in 5.5.28. Is this is an open bug?

Comment: One of my servers has this problem, and the 5.5.27 fixed it.

Comment: But same issue present in 5.5.27.

Comment: Sad to see.
Can you check the 10.0.0 alpha, as they relased today?